# Windows Service Task - Polling Cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, polling, cancellation-token

I am writing a windows service and found an example which suggests writing a polling windows services as follows:

```
private void Poll()
{
    CancellationToken cancellationPoll = ctsPoll.Token;
    while (!cancellationPoll.WaitHandle.WaitOne(tsInterval))
    {
        PollDatabase();
        // Occasionally check the cancellation state.
        if (cancellationPoll.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am a little confused when it comes to the cancellation and if i need both the cancellationPoll.WaitHandle.WaitOne() and cancellationPoll.IsCancellationRequested or are they doing the same thing and only one is required?

Comment: Do you want a suspension of execution between polling?

Answer (score 1):

The `!cancellationPoll.WaitHandle.WaitOne(tsInterval)` is there to ensure the polling interval so you will have at least `tsIntetval` between polling(+ the operation duration):

```
--tsInterval--|--operation--|--tsInterval--|...
```

If you look at the documentation for `CancellationToken.WaitHandle` it says the following:

> A WaitHandle that is signaled when the token is canceled.

So in your case the operation `cancellationPoll.IsCancellationRequested` is sufficient because you don't have anything after it. But imagine the situation like this:

```
while (!cancellationPoll.WaitHandle.WaitOne(tsInterval))
{
    //long operation A

    if (cancellationPoll.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        break;
    }

    //long operation B

    if (cancellationPoll.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        break;
    }
    //long operation C
}
```

In this case it makes sense to occasionally check the cancellation state to avoid running long operation...

Comment: I still makes not a lot of sense because you can put third` IsCancellationRequested` for consistency of handling and avoid a confusion like arisen in this topic.

Comment: The point is that you do not want to even run action B or action C if token has been signaled, so you don't want to wait for the next loop iteration... Yes you can put also the third one as well but the gain is negligible...

Comment: I consider the reasoning only from the `IsCancellationRequested` vs `WaitHandle` standpoint and don't see any reason to mix the approaches as mixing has obvious downsides and the same result can be achieved only by using 3 of `IsCancellationRequested`.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov What are the obvious downsides?

Comment: The most obvious is readability - you see it makes confusion while should be easily readable. If your code reader is familiar with one approach and unfamiliar with another it will make he/she dig into details of each method. For me it enough justification to avoid this but additionally there are aspects related to the resources de-allocation - if `CancellationToken` comes from an external components which you don't control chances that `CancellationTokenSource` life-cycle can be not properly implemented and by accessing `WaitHandle` you implicitly allocate new resource inside CTS.

Comment: OK readability, fine but the actual requirement is to have polling interval. So you want to use different approach than `WaitHandle` then?

Comment: I don't see a polling interval in the requirements.

Comment: `while (!cancellationPoll.WaitHandle.WaitOne(tsInterval))` you have `tsInterval` it is polling interval...

Comment: This code is from example author found somewhere and author is asking about relevance of this code rather than a source of requirements.

Answer (score -1):

The `!cancellationPoll.WaitHandle.WaitOne(tsInterval)` is needed so that you do not wait the whole time. `WaitOne(tsInterval)` will either return because the token recevied a singnal to cancel or because the time is run out. If the token recieved a signal to cancel `WaitOne(tsInterval)` will return `true` and so end the loop.

For example, if you would do something like:

```
while(true)
{
    // long operation
    if (cancellationPoll.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        break;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(tsInterval);
}
```

if then the cancellation is reqested while the thread is blocked by `Thread.Sleep()` the whole operation would not know that an cancellation is reqested not until `Thread.Sleep()` is finished and the next loop run has come to the `if` statement.

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep` is a speculation there, it's unknown whether it's needed or not. Considering that `PollDatabase` implies some I/O it isn't needed at all. But even if you need a functionality to suspend scheduling of a thread in general case typically the very short period is used, which is measured in tens of milliseconds or less, and considering that a cancellation signal comes once, in average case scenario you'll get half of this period loss only once, which in vast majority of known cancellation scenarios just can be neglected.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov Considering that in the original code `tsInterval` is given to `WaitOne()`, I'm not wrong in assuming that there should be an suspension of the execution.

Answer (score -1):

The waiting of `WaitHanlde` is redundant here as from the result standpoint it does the same as `IsCancellationRequested` - indicates that cancellation is requested (but does it in slightly different way). So for your case you can choose single method: either `WaitHandle` or `IsCancellationRequested`. But please keep in mind that `WaitHandle` is `IDisposable` and requires disposing the associated `CancellationTokenSource`. If you choose to use `IsCancellationRequested` don't forget to add a call which is supposed to reschedule thread such as `Thread.Sleep` in order not to over-utilize the CPU resources.
One of scenario when `WaitHanlde` can be applied is when you need to wait for a handle and would like to introdece cancellation semantic to this wait:

```
 WaitHandle.WaitAny(new [] { handleToWait, cancellationHandle });
```

Comment: It is not correct that both approches does the same. The wait handle solution solves the problem to be abel to cancel while the thread waits for the next polling iteration. The `IsCancellationRequested` soltution solves the problem to cancel while an polling iteration is in progress.

Comment: @Ackdari If you read carefully you'll see that I specified they do the same from result standpoint - you can check it in the source code. They way how they do this is different - that's exactly what I said - so what's wrong with my statement ?

Comment: @DmytroMualov it is wrong to state that both soltutions produce the same behaviour. If you replace the `WaitOne()` with `true` and add a call to `Thread.Sleep()` and lets say the waiting time is 5 min. This will lead to the situation that the operation was cancelled but it will not know it for 5 minutes.

Comment: @Ackdari Sadly that you are unable to read carefully because behavior and result aren't the same things. Why are you mentioning `Thread.Sleep` at all ? It has nothing to do with cancellation token. I added it as en example of call to remove the thread from the scheduling queue but not for a functionality to wait for a cancellation token. If there are other thread rescheduling calls (IO, wait ops) you don't need that. The functionality to wait for a cancellation for significant period of time is redundant at all unless you wait for another handle so example with 5 mins is irrelevant.